# How to build a subgroup $H\leq S_4$ having order $8$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can anyone explain me what would be the procedure for building a subgroup $H\leq S_4$ of order $8$?

I started obviously as  $H=\{id$.  Then I added two disjoint $2$-cycles $(1\ 2), (3\ 4)$ for they commute and they are equal to their inverse, that is, $$H=\{id, (1\ 2), (3\ 4), $$ then I added the product of this $2$-cycles, $$H=\{id, (1\ 2), (3\ 4), (1\ 2)(3\ 4).$$

Now I don't know what I should add because I have to worry about both with the products and inverses.

Is there a general guideline for building this kind of subgroup?

Thanks

**Obs:**

**(i)** $S_4$ is the group of the permutations of the first $4$ integers.

Thanks

Comment: **Hint**: Since $H$ has order 8, its elements must have order $1,2,4$ or $8$, by Lagrange's theorem.  On the other hand, elements of $S_4$ have orders $1,2,3,4$.  What is left if you discard from $S_4$ all the elements of order $3$?

Comment: The Klein $4$-group has order $4$! You might try starting with a $4$-cycle such as $(1,2,3,4)$ and attempt to build up a dihedral group.

Comment: Note also that such a subgroup, since it can't consist solely of even permutations ($8\nmid 12$) must have $4$ odd and $4$ even permutations, so other than $e$, there must be exactly $3$ even permutations.

Comment: To your group you can add a 4-cycle such that its square is $(12)(34)$. Can you find such a 4-cycle?

Answer (score 5):

A subgroup of order $8$ in $S_4$ is a $2$-Sylow subgroup, so it is the [wreath product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wreath_product)
$$S_2\wr S_2= (S_2\times S_2)\rtimes S_2,$$
where the right most $S_2$ acts by permuting components of the first two. In other words, let the first $S_2$ be $\{1,(12)\}$, the second be $\{1,(34)\}$, then the third is $\{1,(13)(24)\}$.

---

Another way is to see that the subgroup
$$\{1,(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}$$
is normal in $S_4$, and then take any of the transpositions $(ij)$ as an extra generator.

Comment: What are the odds someone asking such a basic question has the faintest idea what a wreath product is?

Comment: @Timbuc Very likely. In fact I would guess that the OP didn't know about Sylow subgroups. That explains the explicit constructions.

Comment: @timbuc Answers on this site aren't only for the person asking the question.  They are intended to form a permanent collection for perusal by future visitors.  Some of those visitors may be interested in a solution involving wreath products.

Comment: @MJD. I'd agree with that as long as the answer *also* covers the question in the assumed level the OP has, as answering the question for the poster **is** the main goal of this site, I believe.

Answer (score 3):

Look at $S_4$ as the group of permutations of the vertices ABCD of a square.

The plane isometries fixing the square induce obvious permutations on the vertices, defining a map
$$
D_4\hookrightarrow S_4.
$$
Its image is your subgroup of order $8$.

You get all others by reshuffling the labels of the vertices, since this operation induces an inner automorphism of $S_4$ and you know that all subgroups of order $8$ of $S_4$, being its $2$-Sylows, are conjugated.

Comment: downvoting should be justified .....