# Find all subgroup of order $8$ of $S_4$ and verify that $N_{2^3} \equiv 1 (\mod 2)$ and divide $3$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Since $\mid S_4 \mid = 2^3 3$, the permutation group possesses at leat
>   one subgroup of order $8$ (Sylow's theorem). Find all subgroup of
>   order $8$ of $S_4$ and verify that $N_{2^3} \equiv 1 (\mod 2)$
>   ($N_{p^2}$ is the number of subgroup of cardinality $p^s$) and divide
>   $3$.

I construct a set from the dihedral group $D_4$. I got 
$$A = \{(1 \ 2 \ 3 \ 4), (1 \ 3)(2 \ 4),\ (1 \ 4 \ 3 \ 2),\ 1_A, (1 \ 3)(2 \ 4),\ (1 \ 4)(2 \ 3),\ (3 \ 4)(1 \ 2)\}.$$

I know how to verify that a set is a subgroup, but this way is very long.

Can you explain me how to show that this set is a subgroup?

Is it the only sub-group of order $8$ of $S_4$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S_4$ has $3$ different subgroups of order $8$, which are all isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_4$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/982665/how-to-build-a-subgroup-h-leq-s-4-having-order-8?rq=1). We have indeed three different dihedral subgroups in $S_4$, as was explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1357406/dihedral-subgroups-of-s-4?rq=1). Hence $N_8=3$, which is congruent $1$ modulo $2$. They are subgroups, because they are exactly the Sylow-2-subgroups.